# zabbix: unrecognized service

Tags: service, installation, redhat, zabbix

I try to install zabbix, and I have installed this package:zabbix-release-3.4-1.el7.centos.noarch

I use this command to install zabbix:

yum install zabbix-server-mysql zabbix-web-mysql

Output:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * amzn-main: packages.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com
 * amzn-updates: packages.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com
9 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package zabbix-server-mysql.x86_64 0:3.0.11-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: zabbix-server-mysql-3.0.11-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: zabbix-server-mysql-3.0.11-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libnetsnmp.so.31()(64bit) for package: zabbix-server-mysql-3.0.11-1.el7.x86_64
---> Package zabbix-web-mysql.noarch 0:3.0.11-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: zabbix-web = 3.0.11-1.el7 for package: zabbix-web-mysql-3.0.11-1.el7.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package zabbix-server-mysql.x86_64 0:3.0.11-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: zabbix-server-mysql-3.0.11-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: zabbix-server-mysql-3.0.11-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libnetsnmp.so.31()(64bit) for package: zabbix-server-mysql-3.0.11-1.el7.x86_64
---> Package zabbix-web.noarch 0:3.0.11-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php >= 5.4 for package: zabbix-web-3.0.11-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-ldap for package: zabbix-web-3.0.11-1.el7.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php56.x86_64 0:5.6.31-1.134.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php56-cli(x86-64) = 5.6.31-1.134.amzn1 for package: php56-5.6.31-1.134.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php56-common(x86-64) = 5.6.31-1.134.amzn1 for package: php56-5.6.31-1.134.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-mmn = 20120211x86-64 for package: php56-5.6.31-1.134.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php56-common for package: php56-5.6.31-1.134.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: httpd24 for package: php56-5.6.31-1.134.amzn1.x86_64
---> Package php56-ldap.x86_64 0:5.6.31-1.134.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package zabbix-server-mysql.x86_64 0:3.0.11-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: zabbix-server-mysql-3.0.11-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: zabbix-server-mysql-3.0.11-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libnetsnmp.so.31()(64bit) for package: zabbix-server-mysql-3.0.11-1.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package httpd24.x86_64 0:2.4.27-3.75.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: httpd24-tools = 2.4.27-3.75.amzn1 for package: httpd24-2.4.27-3.75.amzn1.x86_64
---> Package php56-cli.x86_64 0:5.6.31-1.134.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package php56-common.x86_64 0:5.6.31-1.134.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php56-process(x86-64) = 5.6.31-1.134.amzn1 for package: php56-common-5.6.31-1.134.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php56-xml(x86-64) = 5.6.31-1.134.amzn1 for package: php56-common-5.6.31-1.134.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php56-jsonc(x86-64) for package: php56-common-5.6.31-1.134.amzn1.x86_64
---> Package zabbix-server-mysql.x86_64 0:3.0.11-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: zabbix-server-mysql-3.0.11-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: zabbix-server-mysql-3.0.11-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libnetsnmp.so.31()(64bit) for package: zabbix-server-mysql-3.0.11-1.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package httpd24-tools.x86_64 0:2.4.27-3.75.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package php56-jsonc.x86_64 0:1.3.6-1.19.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libjson-c.so.2()(64bit) for package: php56-jsonc-1.3.6-1.19.amzn1.x86_64
---> Package php56-process.x86_64 0:5.6.31-1.134.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package php56-xml.x86_64 0:5.6.31-1.134.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package zabbix-server-mysql.x86_64 0:3.0.11-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: zabbix-server-mysql-3.0.11-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: zabbix-server-mysql-3.0.11-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libnetsnmp.so.31()(64bit) for package: zabbix-server-mysql-3.0.11-1.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package json-c.x86_64 0:0.11-6.8.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package zabbix-server-mysql.x86_64 0:3.0.11-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: zabbix-server-mysql-3.0.11-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: zabbix-server-mysql-3.0.11-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libnetsnmp.so.31()(64bit) for package: zabbix-server-mysql-3.0.11-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Conflict: php56-5.6.31-1.134.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts php < 5.5.22-1.98
--> Processing Conflict: httpd24-2.4.27-3.75.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts httpd < 2.4.27
--> Processing Conflict: php56-process-5.6.31-1.134.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts php-process < 5.5.22-1.98
--> Processing Conflict: php56-common-5.6.31-1.134.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 5.5.22-1.98
--> Processing Conflict: php56-xml-5.6.31-1.134.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts php-xml < 5.5.22-1.98
--> Processing Conflict: httpd24-tools-2.4.27-3.75.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts httpd-tools < 2.4.27
--> Processing Conflict: php56-cli-5.6.31-1.134.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts php-cli < 5.5.22-1.98
```

Also show this part, Error occured, so I can't install zabbix properly

> --> Finished Dependency Resolution
>       Error: httpd24 conflicts with httpd-2.2.34-1.15.amzn1.x86_64
>       Error: Package: zabbix-server-mysql-3.0.11-1.el7.x86_64 (zabbix)
>                  Requires: systemd
>       Error: php56-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
>       Error: Package: zabbix-server-mysql-3.0.11-1.el7.x86_64 (zabbix)
>                  Requires: libnetsnmp.so.31()(64bit)
>       Error: httpd24-tools conflicts with httpd-tools-2.2.34-1.15.amzn1.x86_64
>       Error: php56-process conflicts with php-process-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
>       Error: php56 conflicts with php-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
>       Error: php56-xml conflicts with php-xml-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
>       Error: php56-cli conflicts with php-cli-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
>        You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
>        You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

Can I know what is the issue here?

I fix this problem for long time, anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is package dependency. You are trying to install RefHat7 (rhel7) package, which requires package systemd. Unfortunately, your OS Amazon Linux doesn't support systemd.

Solutions:

- switch to rhel/centos AMI and use rhel zabbix packages
- use some repo, which provides zabbix package for Amazon Linux (don't mix it with rhel packages)